# Remove part of text within P tag after a " " separator

Tags: jquery, string, text

My Markup is like this :

```
<div class="article">
 <p class="date">16-05-2011 15:28:24</p>
</div>
```

This output is generated by a CMS and I searched for everywhere to modify the output but I didn't reach a solution.

I want to use jQuery to remove the "hour" from the date paragraph.

Saying I don't want any text after the "space" so that the day-month-year will show up only.

Any idea how to achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty easy loop, splitting by a space with a limit of 1 item:

```
$('p.date').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().split(" ",1)[0]);
});
```

Comment: Working perfectly ... I spent like an hour trying to search for an explode() function like that in PHP but simply split() does seem to do the job. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var date = $('p.date').html(); // get date content
  var split = date.split(" "); // explode by space
  $('div.date').html(split[0]); // setting the html with the first piece
</script>
```

not tested, but I think this should be it. If there are more then 1 div, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('p.date').each(function(index) {
      var date = $(this).html();
      var split = date.split(' ');
      $(this).html(split[0]);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: `div.date` is the wrong selector. you should use `p.date` instead